# GIT: (Kohana) Project setup

Tags: git, github, kohana, git-submodules

I am developing a kohana project. 
There is a repository on github for the framework core. 
Also, they are many modules on separate repositories that i need (orm, acl, email, etc)

I will be creating and working on my own modules, and want to have them in a unfuddle repository (only my modules would be *physically* there), but when I checkout the project I want to have the kohana and modules pulled as well along with mine. (submodules?)

I'm pretty new to GIT, any pointers on how to accomplish the set up wold be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/tutorials/git

This describes how to properly setup a kohana project with git submodules.

Comment: It's all git, so you can checkout 3.0/master branch, or a specific tag: v3.0.12

Comment: ok, you have put me in the right track. However, as I said, im quite blind with git, and I want to do something a bit different. Would you mind to check my answer? Also, i will mark your answer as correct...

Answer (score 0):

[The problem with this is that since the whole kohana directory is a submodule, the modules that I add, are not being stored...]

Ok, @zombor showed me the way.

This is what I've done, and I would like to know if it smells...

I decided to pull from `github.com/kohana/kohana` instead of `github.com/kohana/core` because it provides the whole *skeleton* of the framework.

```
git submodule add git://github.com/kohana/kohana.git kohana
cd kohana
git checkout -b 3.0 origin/3.0/master
git sumodule init
git submodule update
cd ..
git add kohana
git commit -m "moved to kohana 3.0/master"
git push 
git push unfuddle master
```

Comment: No, don't do this. You don't want kohana's history in your main repo. If you are using 3.0 (I dont know why you'd be doing this for a new project), you should follow the git guide in the 3.0 docs: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/tutorials/git

Comment: well, it is not a new project, I have it locally and have to deploy on a server using git...